# Can I still get my free games from the PSN Welcome Back promotion?

Tags: psn

When the PlayStation Network came back online, we could download 2 full games for free.

I downloaded `Infamous`, then decided to wait to download the second one.

Do you know if I can still download the second game? Where in the menu of PlayStation store can I find it?

Did I have a limited time to download these games?

For information, I remember that one of these game was `Little Big Planet`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Playstation [Welcome Bac](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2011/06/03/welcome-back/)k promotion has unfortunately expired. It ended on July 5th, 2011. It was [temporarily extended](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2011/07/01/public-service-announcement-claim-your-free-games-now/), as its previous end date was July 1st. However, the offer is definitely over now.

Comment: And the games selection sucked :P My opinion...

Comment: LBP was a good choice for the selection but I already bought it :-( I admit that the other games were not my cup of tea.

Comment: Infamous is definitely on my list of "games everyone should play once during their life."  It's up there with Zelda 64 and Starfox.  LBP is good too.  Unfortunately, I had already bought them both.  Dead Nation was fun too.

Comment: I missed out by two days :(

Answer (score 2):

If you added one of the free games to your cart and "bought" it (for free) before July 5th 2011, then it will appear in your PlayStation Store download history and you will still be able to download it even though the offer has now expired. Otherwise, you will no longer be able to get get those games for free.

Comment: Nope, I didn't put the second game in my cart.